# difference between `discuss me` and `discuss with me`

Tags: prepositions

> Would you like to discuss me more in details?

Is this correct sentence?

I was thinking as

> Would you like to discuss with me in more details?

Or are they the same meaning?

If so, which is more polite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say "discuss me" then the word "me" is the *direct object*, which means you are the subject of discussion. When you say "discuss with me" then "me" becomes the *indirect object* so instead the details (of some other subject) are being discussed, and you are involved in the discussion.

Comment: `discuss me` means discuss about me?

Comment: I’ve edited out the assertion about one being “more correct” than another. 1. Without context, we don’t know which better fits the situation. 2. Grammatically, both are admissible as the rest of your answer (which I’ve upvoted) points out.

Comment: Yes, because _discuss_ means _talk about_.

Comment: @Lawrence I just don't understand. I'm not sure ELL would be happy with this question as it stands.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I take it that you’re making a general comment since I haven’t mentioned ELL or addressed the question _per se_ in my comment. (The answer as it now stands addresses the question well.) As for the possible migration your comment implies, I haven’t been active on ELL for some time, so I’m not sure what standards they apply to the ‘research’ requirement etc these days. However, mixing up direct and indirect objects is common enough for learners that I’d have thought ELL _would_ welcome the topic.